# setting 2 div next to each other

Tags: html, css, css-float

Lets say I have 2 divs

```
    width: 140%;
    padding: 13px;
    height: 20;
    float: left;
```

how do I make them next to each other? ( the best way I can )

Comment: if you've 2 divs with 'width:140%' you cant make them sit next to each other. Except you use 'width:50%' or less.

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: width 140% for one div and collectively it will become 280%, still two div should sit next to each other. that means your page will have a horizontal scroll. is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @NileshMahajan if so how can i do this?

Comment: @Facondo: check my answer, let me know if it works or not for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div>World</div>

div {
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 200px;
    height:100px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider this, if the page is 100%..

How are 2 divs of a total of 280% going to fit inside a 100% page?

Also, the height should be written as `height: 20px;`.

This would be the correct way to write this:

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Or even better:

```
div {
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block.
  height: 20px;
  padding: 13px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making the divs wider than the screen with `width:140%` making them equal less than 100% is what you are looking for [example](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/KdXVYB) here we set the width to 45% accounting for the padding so the align correctly

```
.box {
    width: 45%;
    padding: 13px;
    height: 20;
    background:blue;
    margin-right: 20px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for the case which you have stated in your question, the best possible solution I have is.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.wrapper{
    display:table;
    width:280%;
}
.box {
    width:50%;
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid 2px red;
    padding: 13px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

basically a `table` layout using `div` can achieve the result you are expecting.

I took 280% width for the wrapper div and 50% for the boxes, eventually it will become 140% for each individual box, as you expected.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08c9nqq0/)